# How to create Fluid motion in android

Tags: android, android-canvas, graphics2d, fluid, fluid-dynamics

i need to render Fluid inside a bottle and when the device is rotated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fluid dynamics isn't a simple topic. The simplest example of [fluid flow is 2D, incompressible, irrotational, laminar flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation). I'd start by looking into that.

You cannot do it in a week, you'll have to learn it.

You can learn from this java example http://www.jbox2d.org/liquid/ Unless your simulation is very small and 2D, you'll probably need to use a C/C++ library with the NDK to get any reasonable framerate.

Google did release a Physics library based on box2d (using NDK) for android. http://google.github.io/liquidfun/ This could be a good resource to get started but unless you understand Physics well, you won't be able to do much.

Comment: The liquidFun is great to start with.

Comment: Thanks Taranfx for your comments, i will go through this...so there is no way i can do that with Android SDK !!